# Format JSON PHP from MySQL Query

Tags: php, json, post, get

I have a question about formating a json in php. Here is my code

public function testing() {

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('trash_table');
    $this->db->where('Description',$_POST['Descp']);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if($q->num_rows() > 0 )      
     //here should be something better
    print json_encode($q->result());
```

}

With my current simple php code, I'm just getting everything as a JSONArray.

[

```
  {"ID":1,"Description":"hello",

  {"ID":2,"Description":"hellou"}
```

]

But I want to format it on my own way, something like this...Hope you guys help. Thank you in advanced!

{

```
"Answer": {

    "Success": "Yup"
          },
```

"List": [

```
    {"ID":1,    
    "Description":"hello"},

    {"ID":2,    
    "Description":"hellou"}]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array(
  'Answer' => array('Sucess'=>'Yup'),
  'List' => array(
     array('id' => 1, 'Description' => 'hello'),
  )
);
print json_encode($result);
```

Will print:

```
{"Answer":{"Sucess":"Yup"},"List":[{"id":1,"Description":"hello"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`$list = $q->result();
     $result = array( "Answer" => 
                  array ( "success" => "Yup" ),
                  "List" => $list 
                );
     print json_encode($result);`